# index allocation maximum file size

Tags: operating-system

The following is a sample quiz problem about index-allocating of file systems.
I am kind of stuck. I think that the answer might be 512^3 bytes, but I am not sure. Could anyone explain please.

> An OS uses three-level indexing for file allocation. If an index block
>   contains n pointers to other blocks (data or index), what is the
>   maximum size allowed for a file using such an allocation scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.

The first node has n pointers as given in the question. Typically, for a triple indirect system that means there are n-3 "direct" pointers pointing to data and 3 indirect pointers pointing to another index block.

This image from Harvard University linked below:
[image: Multi-Level Indexed Allocation]

The image shows that the single indirect pointer points to only *one* index block and then to data blocks. The double indirect pointer points to one index block which contains n more pointers to more indexes! The triple indirect pointer is the same except that it has *3* layers of index blocks before getting to the data blocks.

So there are n-3 direct blocks;

n single indirect blocks;

n^2 double indirect blocks and

n^3 triple indirect blocks.

given an arbitrary block size, the total max size becomes:

```
blocksize*(n^3 + n^2 + n + (n-3))
```

or

```
blocksize*(n^3 + n^2 + 2n - 3)
```

Check out these slides by Harvard University: http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~mdw/course/cs161/sp07/notes/ffs.pdf

Also this site describes how 4.3 BSD UNIX implements it: https://web.stanford.edu/~ouster/cgi-bin/cs140-winter16/lecture.php?topic=files

Comment: Re-reading your question, you might need to ask your professor to clarify. If he just means a triple level tree structure then the answer is simply n^3 x blocksize.